# How do I escape Ampersand (&) from current working directory %~dp0 in batch file

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I usually get the current working directory by giving the batch command %~dp0 for combine multiple csv files. 
But I encountered ampersand (&) symbol while getting current working directories which makes batch file broke after the '&' saying the path after & is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Can any of you guys please help me in modifying my below script in identifying & and replacing it with ^& (as this can escape the & and run the batch file). Any of your suggestions is appreciated;

Here is my code:

```
@echo off

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0             - How to escape & in this line???

ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM set count to 1
set cnt=1

REM for each file that matches *.csv

for %%i in (*.csv) do (

REM if count is 1 it's the first time running

  if !cnt!==1 (

REM push the entire file complete with header into combined.csv - this will also create combined.csv

for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv

REM otherwise, make sure we're not working with the combined file and
  ) else if %%i NEQ combined.csv (

REM push the file without the header into combined.csv
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )

REM increment count by 1
  set /a cnt+=1
)

cmd \k
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting quotation marks around `%~dp0` should be enough:

```
...
pushd "%~dp0"
...
```

Btw, I don't understand why you use `pushd`. You don't `popd` anywhere in your code so `pushd` seems useless. If I understand `ECHO Set working directory` correctly, you should replace `pushd` with `CD %~dp0`.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for the suggestion, Now I am able to escape the '&'

Comment: @NarendraPamuru If this helped you, you should mark it as accepted answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to it.

Comment: If you use CD instead of PUSHD, then you should include the `\D` option.