# Using %~dp0 on non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: batch-file

I am currently using `%~dp0` in my batch file to refer to the directory of the batch file, and then `setx` to set it to an environment variable.

However I realised that if there are non-alphanumeric characters, such as `&` in my folder path, the environment variable is not set correctly.

Is there a way to do `setx` such that the correct path appears?

Comment: Double quote it. `"%~dp0"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape Ampersand (&) from current working directory %~dp0 in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977344/how-do-i-escape-ampersand-from-current-working-directory-dp0-in-batch-file)